# Highcharts adjust first and last tick on x-axis to direct values

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, axis

My current x-axis looks like in following image:

[My current x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjXOY.jpg)

I need to adjust first and last tick to the lowest and biggest value.
So lets say first tick would be 26.4.2015 18:38:36 and last tick would be 27.4.2015 9:07:27. Rest of ticks should be calculated automatically.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    zoomType: "x"
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    title: {
      text: "Time"
    },
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    min: 1430073516000,
    tickmarkPlacement: "on",
    showFirstLabel: true,
    showLastLabel: true,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    labels: {
      formatter() {
        if (this.isFirst || this.isLast) {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat("%e.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", this.value);
        } else {
          return this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Value"
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  series: [
    {
      id: "First",
      name: "First",
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 242, 542, 456, 422, 445, 884, 123],
      pointStart: 1430073516000,
      pointInterval: 60000
    },
    {
      id: "Second",
      name: "Second",
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      data: [0, 0, 0, 25, 356, 427, 242, 456, 811, 422, 541, 5, 0],
      pointStart: 1430073516000,
      pointInterval: 60000
    }
  ]
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vy5uL2aw/1/

Comment: You need to share you series data at least, if you want an answer. Preferably a jsfiddle with your current graph.

Comment: JSFiddle added.

Comment: You can't set some ticks, and let the chart automatically generate others, on the same axis. Two things you could try: 1) create a 2nd `xAxis` where you only specify those two ticks (you'll need to adjust offset, hide the line, etc.) 2) add two `plotLines` to you chart and use their labels to achieve your goal. Otherwise you can use the `tickPositioner()` function to set all of the ticks appropriately on a single axis.

Comment: As addition to jlbriggs comment, here you can find simple example how to work with tickPositioner on getting your xAxis labels: http://jsfiddle.net/vy5uL2aw/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you, it works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was following function added to xAxis object.

```
tickPositioner() {
    let tickPositions = this.tickPositions;
    tickPositions[0] = this.dataMin;
    tickPositions[tickPositions.length - 1] = this.dataMax;
    return tickPositions;
}
```